# jquery DataTables. How to get filtered (visible) rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a button that apply filter to jquery datatable

```
$("#buttonFilter").button().click(function() {
                if (lboxColor.val() != null) {
                    jqTable.fnFilter($("option:selected", lboxColor).text(), 1);
                }
            });
```

It shows me for example 47 rows from 60.
I tried .fnGetData() and fnGetNodes() but it shows me all rows, but not filtered.
How could I get 47 rows?

Comment: Question is closed. I used method from plugin for datatables fnGetFilteredData() . http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api#how_to

Comment: If the question is closed, write your own answer and accept it after two days.

Answer (score 33):

I've been searching for about an hour, for anyone using DataTables 1.10+ if you want to get the filtered (better term: "searched") rows:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({...});

function selectOnlyFiltered(){
   var filteredRows = table.rows({filter: 'applied'});
}
```

Comment: Note that table.rows( {page:'current'} ).data() "sets order=current and search=applied" per https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier in case you wanted to just grab the rows that are visible for the page you're on.

Answer (score 20):

For datatables 1.9 and later this solution works:

```
myDataTableHandle = $('#example1').dataTable(...);
...
...
var myFilteredRows = myDataTableHandle._('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
```

and you won't have to include a separate api plugin.  :)

Comment: Does not work for me :(  It only returns values on the current visible page. E.g. my table info line shows "Showing 1 to 10 of 45,048 entries (filtered from 45,248 total entries)" and the `{"filter":"applied"}` code only gives me 10 values.

Comment: I see that the `fnRecordsDisplay()` **does** give the correct value of 45,048 so there **is a way** to get all the filtered nodes/values. Does anyone know the **REAL** answer?

Comment: FYI - Found the problem - there are no TR nodes for rows on non-visible pages when `bDeferRender` is turned on. See [similar issue here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7454/fngetnodes-only-returning-visible-nodes/p1)

Answer (score 7):

Just in case you want a collection of nodes (DOM elements) just like fngetNodes(), you can use the '$' instead of the '_' like this `table.$('tr', {"filter":"applied"});`

the '_' returns a collection of 'TR' (html elements).

Answer (score 3):

In current versions [selector-modifier](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) uses a slightly different set of properties.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var rows = table.rows({"search" : "applied"});
```

And you can iterate over the cell data like this:

```
table.rows({"search":"applied" }).every( function () {
    var data = this.data();
});
```

Some helpful links:

- https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()
- https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier
- https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()

Answer (score 3):

For those struggling to get **data** from **only one column** AND **only from visible rows**:
you can actually combine the "selectors" like this

```
var total = api
      .column(2, { search: 'applied' }) // <-- only 3rd column && only visible after applied search
      .data()
      .reduce(function (a, b) {
        return floatVal(a) + floatVal(b)
      }, 0)
```

I also notices several sources stating { page: 'current' } would be the right selector for currently visible rows, but this one actually gives you the rows visible after a possible pagination.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, this is a concrete usecase.

```
/**
 * Select all the elements of the datatable which match the current user
 * search (or all if no search).
 */
function dtable_selectAll()
{
    idTable = 'myDataTable';
    var rows = $('#' + idTable).dataTable()
            .$('tr', {"filter":"applied"});
    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance(idTable);
    $(rows).each(function (index, el){
        oTT.fnSelect(el);
    })
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just for completeness, and as Yuri mentioned, there are "plugins" that will provide the filtered [TR Nodes](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnGetFilteredNodes) or [data](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnGetFilteredData).

To use these plugins, you will need to paste the code from those links into your script file.

Comment: I can't seem find the plugin function in the API page, had it been removed?

Answer (score -1):

like if work for you

```
var data = []
table.rows({"search":"applied"}).every(()=>data.push(this.data()))
console.log(data)
```