# Current page wise sorting using datatable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to sort current page only using datatable plugin. Is there any way to do this?

javascript ode:

```
$('#announcementListing-data').DataTable({
        pageLength: 5,
         "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets"  : 'no-sort',
      "orderable": false,
      "order": []
    }],     
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records per page",
            "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
            "info": "_PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
        }       
    });
```

Comment: Check this URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437983/how-to-sort-only-the-current-page-using-jquery-datatable

Answer (score 0):

Bydefault Datatables provide sorting functionality. But if you can sorting for particular column for particular table, you can use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        order: [[ 3, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

Here [ 3, 'desc' ] means (0,1,2,3) fourth column in descending order,  [ 0, 'asc' ] means first column in ascending order.