# Sorting on particular page data on angular datatable

Tags: angularjs

**When we click on sort button in angular data table rendering to 1st page.**

For example my data table contains 100 data.if we select show entries 10 there will be 10 pages.

- If we click on sort button in 5th page it is coming to 1st page
  because it applies sorting on all 100 records.

---

### **so is there any way to apply sorting only on data available on 5th page i.e only on 10 records.**

Comment: for this i recommend you to write shorting criteria in your service part then you can easily handel it in client

Answer (score 0):

You are doing server side sorting by :

> If we click on sort button in 5th page it is coming to 1st page
>   because it applies sorting on all 100 records.

What you need to fetch 5th page and do client side sorting.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Ydu.png)

Comment: for example one object contains 100 records in client side after processing     server side.we can show all records in data table right..

Comment: if we click on show entries 10 there will be 10 pages .

Comment: Your angular "datatable" is third party tool or just <table></table> ?

Comment: <table class="table" datatable="ng" width="100%" dt-options="dtOptions" >

Comment: i think its just table

Comment: So just think you are doing sorting of javascript object of type array. nothing special to angular. with angular you bind to your model

Comment: go through this link

Comment: there are 2 pages right to Showing 3 to 3 of 3 entries.click on page 2.

Comment: then click on sorting button,and see it is rendering to page 1, because it is applying sorting on all contents of the table

Comment: i am searching for a way so that we can apply sorting only on page 2.

Comment: You should edit your question and add relevant datatable tag, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27437983/492258) may help then