# Preserve page number in jquery datatable pagination while sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have implemented a jquery datatable in asp mvc. The records are being fetched correctly, and the sorting working correctly. The data table operates via the server side.

However, I encountered a small issue. When I am on page 3 of the datatable, I perform a sorting but the datable refreshes, returns to page 1 and only sorts records on page 1. What I want to achieve is to make sorting only on the current page that I am.

I have tried making the `stateSave` to `true` like: But the issue persists.

```
var table = $('#employeetable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Employee/GetList",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [

                    { "data": "Name", "name": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Office", "name": "Office" },
                    { "data": "Position", "name": "Position" },
                    { "data": "Age", "name": "Age" },
                    { "data": "Salary", "name": "Salary" },

                ],

                "serverSide": true,
                "order": [0, "asc"],
                "processing": true,
                "stateSave": true

            });
```

Can someone please help to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you sort with DataTables, you sort the entire data set, not just the visible values. So any change in the sort order, would naturally be a new list, so would return you to page 1. It's not possible to just search within the current page, thereby keeping the pagination identical. See this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437983/how-to-sort-only-the-current-page-using-jquery-datatable/27575517), where more details are given as to why this isn't (and shouldn't be) possible.